# Do automatic quick release mechanisms exist?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, measurements, fasteners, forces

I'm imagining something like a cable tie that would automatically release after a certain amount of tension was applied.

I guess a very basic way to do it would be to use different diameter strings that would break when different loads are applied. But I'd ideally want something that is reusable and more accurate than that.

I guess a complicated but reusable and more accurate way of doing it would be a robotic mechanism that measures the tension being applied and automatically releases some type of fastening/catch/clip when that tension threshold is reached. But I'd ideally want something simpler than this.

Any ideas?

Comment: The string is called a mechanical fuse or fusible link. A magnet is reusable. Spring-loaded detents like in a ratchet head are self activating. A screamer is a captive stress relief mechanism.

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/52983/10902

Comment: and https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/52920/14556